# error one very basic Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a very basic ajax call when i click on links 
but it's doesn't seem to work !
Any help woul'd be appreciate : )
I'm working with jQuery 1.9.1

best

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <h3>Chargement de contenus HTML</h3>

    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a class="link_ajax" href="accueil.html">Accueil</a></li>
        <li><a class="link_ajax" href="presentation.html">Présentation</a></li>
        <li><a class="link_ajax" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="result_container"></div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".link_ajax").click(function(event){   
        event.preventDefault();
        var this_url=$(this).attr("href");

        $.ajax({
            url:this_url,
            success:function(response){
                $("#result_container").html(response);
                console.log("success");
                $("#result_container").show();
            },
            error:function(){
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: At the very least you should provide the error you are getting, or the behavior you are seeing compared to what you expect to see.

Comment: Also try to test your ajax call by taking it out of the slideup callback. Ensure it fires properly.

Comment: Also, can you share the HTML? At least the part that is used in the JS (i.e. `.link_ajax` and `#result_container`)

Comment: I'v tried without the slideup function but it's still doesn't seem to work. I got the error message in the console.
For a put a clean html part I must place it in the comment?
Sorry First time on stackOverflow and sorry for my english :)

Comment: You can edit your question and add any new information in there.

Comment: I just made the Update

Comment: Where is `accueil.html` located relative to your current page?  If you are looking at `http://yoursite.com/index.html`, is it located at `http://yoursite.com/accueil.html`?  If not, you will need the correct path in the `href` (either relative or absolute).

Comment: what is the error in your console?

Comment: it's return me the error:function "error"

Comment: Steve
all my html files are placed in the root folder.
The same as index.html

Comment: The most important tool to use when debugging AJAX is the `Network` tab in your web browser's development tools. In Google Chrome press F12 and go to the `Network` tab and refresh your web page to see the AJAX in action. Let me know if Chrome is not your web browser

Comment: Are you using a server (either localhost or somewhere else)? Or are you opening a local file in the browser?  In other words, what does the URl in your browser start with? `http://...` or `file://...`?

Comment: now it's ok 
I thing i'v just messed up with mamp !
Sorry for that guys and thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you try to add `dataType:'html'` to the ajax settings?  Right between `url` and `success`?